# Record Voice calls in android

Tags: android

I want to record phone calls in android. I know that I have to use broadcast receiver but along with broadcast receiver whether I have to use intents or services? If the answer is services then can anyone give the codes for that or both?

Thank you in advance.

here is my code for receiver

```
public class BrCallReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

          @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

            Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
            Intent x = new Intent (c, EavesDropperActivity.class);
            x.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            if (extras != null) {
                String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                Log.w("DEBUG", state);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                Log.w("DEBUG", "MATCHES");
                Toast.makeText(c,
                        "Launching record APP !",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                c.startActivity(x);
            }
        }
    }





}   




<blink>

public class EavesDropperActivity extends Activity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MediaRecorder m_recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    TelephonyManager t_manager ;
    PhoneStateListener p_listener ;
    String record_state;
    Uri file;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Executing Activity",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    t_manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    p_listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)     :
                                                            stop_recorder();
                                                                                           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                            "recorder state : stop" ,
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                                           //t_manager.listen(p_listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
                                                            //finish();
                                                            break;

                case (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)     :
                                                                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                            "recorder state : start" ,

                                                            break;
                case (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)     :

                                                            break;

            }
        }
    };
    t_manager.listen(p_listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    return;

}

public void start_recorder () {
    m_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    m_recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    m_recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +                    "/songs/audionew.3gpp");
    m_recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            m_recorder.prepare();
            m_recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  public void stop_recorder () {
    m_recorder.stop();
    m_recorder.release();
      Uri file = Uri.fromFile(
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/songs/audionew.3gpp"));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "record stored at " + file.toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    t_manager.listen(p_listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    finish();
}

} 

</blink>


My manifest :

<blink>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />    

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.EavesDropperActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="BrCallReceive" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>

</blink>
```

Comment: Give me teh codez!!!1!!1!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot record voice calls on Android for security reasons. You have no access to an in call audio stream at all, with or without root.

This is done to prevent malware from stealing personal data etc.